# How to aggregate one data frame based on other data frame time index?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, plyr

I have two data frame, both are time series data. One is regular interval (daily), the other is irregular. But the second is based on the accumulated value of the first one. For instance these is an example:

```
    date1<-c('2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-04', '2010-01-05','2010-01-06','2010-01-07')

   data.frame1<-data.frame(date=c(as.Date(date1, format= '%Y-%m-%d')), A=c(0.5,10,15,3,10,20,12) , B=c(1.5,1,1.5,3.2,10.5,9,12)) 

       date       A    B
     2010-01-01   0.5  1.5
     2010-01-02  10.0  1.0
     2010-01-03  15.0  1.5
     2010-01-04   3.0  3.2
     2010-01-05  10.0 10.5
     2010-01-06  20.0  9.0
     2010-01-07  12.0 12.0

   date2<-c('2010-01-03', '2010-01-07')

   data.frame2<-data.frame(date=c(as.Date(date2, format= '%Y-%m-%d')), A=c(25.5,45) , B=c(4,34.7)) 

         date      A    B
     2010-01-03   25.5   4
     2010-01-07   45    37.7
```

The first row of data.frame2 (at 2010-01-03) is accumulated value of the three rows of data.frame1 (2010-01-01, 2010-01-02,2010-01-03). 
Now I would like to compare them. But before, I have to do agreggation of data.frame1 so that it can be directly comparable.  Note that the time interval for data.frame2 is irregular. Could anyone help me how to do this? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sapply` for finding the corresponding date in data2 is one way.

```
data.frame1$date <- as.character(data.frame1$date)
data.frame2$date <- as.character(data.frame2$date)

data.frame1$date2 <- sapply(data.frame1$date, function(d) 
  with(data.frame2, min(date[d <= date])))

library(dplyr)
group_by(data.frame1, date2) %>% summarize(A = sum(A), B = sum(B))
```